# VS2010 warning while creating link to a file

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

In my C# project I have some .docx,.xlsx,*.jpg files in an folder, I want to make all these files as `Content` and while `Setup and Deployment Project` I want to add all these files as `Content Output` for That I have done follwing steps:

1. Unload Project from property window and then selected to Edit .csproj file.
2. Added below lines in `<ItemGroup>` to make all files in folder as `Content` and linked them to a folder

   ```
   <Content Include="Lib\MyApp\Support\**\*.*">
      <Link>Support\%(RecursiveDir)%(FileName).%(Extension)</Link>
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
   </Content>
   <Content Include="Lib\MyApp\Files\**\*.*">
      <Link>Files\%(RecursiveDir)%(FileName).%(Extension)</Link>
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
   </Content>
   ```
3. Reload Project

After reloading project I got lots of warning like

> Warning   34 The file 'Lib\MyApp\Files\abc.bmp' could not be added to
>   the project.  Cannot add a link to the file
>   D:\MyApp\Lib\MyApp\Files\abc.bmp. This file is within the project
>   directory tree.

I have Excluded the `Lib` folder from project, Why I am getting such warnings what I am doing wrong? Is it safe to ignore such warnings.

**Update**

After modifying csproj file to this

```
<Content Include="Lib\QOES\Support\**\*.*">
      <Link>Support\%(RecursiveDir)%(FileName)%(Extension)</Link>      
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
      <Visible>false</Visible>
</Content>
<Content Include="Lib\QOES\Files\**\*.*">
      <Link>Files\%(RecursiveDir)%(FileName)%(Extension)</Link>
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
      <Visible>false</Visible>
</Content>
```

after adding `<Visible>false</Visible>` removed warnings, but is this correct way?

Answer (score 1):

Adding `<Visible>false</Visible>` seems to be a very convenient solution to get rid of the Visual Studio warning:

> The file `<filename>` could not be added to the project. This file is
>   within the project directory tree.

Answer (score 0):

According to: [MSDN: The file 'file' could not be added to the project](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tfszfd6t.aspx), one of the reasons is relative paths being ambiguous. Meaning you have the file path `Lib/MyApp/Files/abc.bmp` both as a file path in your project folder as well as on your `D:` drive leading to ambiguity. That is my guess. Adding files by hand to the project folder can lead to issues.

Comment: So..is this safe to ignore or I need to do something?

Comment: Given I've never attempted to manually add my links or files before, I can't give you a definite answer. I would definitely take note of it for the future SHOULD anything come up.

Comment: after adding `<Visible>false</Visible>` removed all the warnings, but I am not sure about is this correct or wrong. See the Update part in question.

Answer (score 0):

In my case where I wanted to place a native binary next to the executable, using `<TargetPath>` instead of `<Link>` worked:

```
<Content Include="Lib\somelibrary.dll">
   <TargetPath>somelibrary.dll</TargetPath>
   <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
</Content>
```